# How to restore text file encoding back to UTF-8 after SED command

Tags: sed, encoding

I received an utf-8 encoded Indian language text file through Google Cloud Vision (OCR). I did some processing on the file using `sed` and now the file shows strange characters.

`file -bi 100.txt` shows `text/plain; charset=unknown-8bit` (after sed)

Original file shows this:

> 1 YYHI6808794 ಹೆನರು ಮಿಲ್ಕಾ ಗಂಡನ ಹೆಸರು ನರೇಶ ದಿವಾಕರ ಮನೆ ನಂ 1 ವಯನ್ನು 40
>   ಲಿಂಗ ಹೆಣ್ಣು

Processed file shows this:

> 1 YYHI6808794 à²¹à³à²¨à²°à³ à²®à²¿à²²à³à²à²¾ à²à²à²¡à²¨
>   à²¹à³à²¸à²°à³ à²¨à²°à³à²¶ à²¦à²¿à²µà²¾à²à²° à²®à²¨à³ à²¨à² 1
>   à²µà²¯à²¨à³à²¨à³ 40 à²²à²¿à²à² à²¹à³à²£à³à²£à³

This is the command I ran:

`sed 's/[]*"._,()•&[-]//g; s/^[ L\/]*//; s/  */ /g; s/ಹೆಣ್ಣು/&\n/; s/ಗಂಡು /&\n/;/^$/d;/!/d' oldfile.txt > newfile.txt`

Is there any way to restore it back to original encoding?

Comment: Some sed operations are reversible, some are not. Do you remember what you did?

Comment: @Beta Yes I do. How to reverse it?

Comment: If you tell us what you did, *maybe* we can help.

Comment: @Beta this is what I did:
`sed 's/[]*"._,()•&[-]//g; s/^[ L\/]*//; s/  */ /g; s/ಹೆಣ್ಣು/&\n/; s/ಗಂಡು /&\n/;/^$/d;/!/d' oldfile.txt > newfile.txt`
then the oldfile got deleted due to some glitch in my code

Comment: That command doesn't turn your "original" text into your "processed" text, and it is not reversible since it deletes some characters.